# Replacing component in grouplayout

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

I am trying to replace components in `jpanel` using `replace()` in `GroupLayout` but it didn't worked. I tried to google it but didn't found any helpful solution. Can any one please tell me where do I making mistake?

Here is my code:

```
contentPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            contentPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(contentPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        contentPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            contentPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(contentPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
```

I am trying to replace the panel with another panel on button click

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          contentPanelLayout.replace(contentPanel,anotherPanel);
}
});
```

I've read the java docs, but not found any helpful.

Comment: It might help you [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html)

Comment: Call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, search "How to replace/add/remove a swing comonent"

Comment: I am trying to replace the panel with another panel on button click == CardLayout,